# Batch script to move video files to folder based on WidthxHeight

Tags: batch, batch-file, media, folder-redirection

I'm currently trying to code a batch script that will move certain video files (mainly .mp4's) to a new sub-folder based on Width and Height to make encoding faster by cutting out the manual labor of putting video files that i don't need to resize with ffmpeg to a new folder.

My process is, for example, like this:
I have a folder with 200 video files, all range in video resolution between 480p and 4K, Vertical and Horizontal. If the resolution is 1280x720/720x1280 or smaller i don't need to resize them and can encode them with -vf "scale=-1:-1". If Vertical videos are bigger than 720x1280 i use -vf "scale=-1:1280" and Horizontal -vf "scale=1280:-1" to cut down size of video files to store them. Currently i would need to go through all 200 video files manually and move them accordingly which is a timesink.

So far i'm using MediaInfo CLI to grab Width and Height like this:
mediainfo --Inform="Video;%Width%x%Height%" VIDEOFILE
mediainfo --Inform="Video;%Height%x%Width%" VIDEOFILE

```
@echo off

rem Variables
set MEDIAINFO=C:\dont_alter\MediaInfo_CLI_22.06_Windows_x64\MediaInfo.exe

rem Script
:loopscript
mkdir no_resize
for %%a in (*.mp4) do set MP4FILE=%%~na
for /f "delims=" %%b in ('mediainfo --Inform="Video;%Width%" %MP4FILE%.mp4 2^>^&1') do set "video_width=%%b"
for /f "delims=" %%c in ('mediainfo --Inform="Video;%Height%" %MP4FILE%.mp4 2^>^&1') do set "video_height=%%c"
echo %video_width% and %video_height%
pause
if %video_width% LEQ 1280 & if %video_height% LEQ 720 do (
        move /y %MP4FILE%.mp4 no_resize
        if not errrorlevel=0 goto errorhandler
        )
goto :loopscript

:errorhandler
echo An error occured...
pause

:eof
```

This is what i've come up with so far but i don't know how to make 2 for each loops independent of each other in the same script.

I assume i would need 2 for each loops, one for Horizontal and one for Vertical.

Not sure how to make this work. Anyone who can help out?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: #1 [call is your friend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10149194/something-like-a-function-method-in-batch-files) when doing a for loop from batch.  You will get a hit for each line and not clobber your variable.  EnableDelayedExpansion will also do this but we hates it.  Others loves it.  #2 piping stderr into stdout is not helping you.  If it is an error message, you certainly dont want that in your variable.  That is the 2 redirecting to &1 part.  #3 PowerShell is probably a better shell to host this sort of code.  You probably don't even need the mediainfo stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to get both (`%%Width%% and %%Height%%"`) on the same line and use `findstr` to help select the files.

```bath
@echo off

cd /d "%~dp0" && 2>nul mkdir .\no_resize

set "_mdinf=C:\dont_alter\MediaInfo_CLI_22.06_Windows_x64\MediaInfo.exe"
set "_avoid=1050 1080 1366 1440 1680 1920 2160 2560 3840 4320 7760 7680 10240 10328"

for %%a in (*.mp4)do (
     %_mdinf% --Inform="Video;%%Width%% and %%Height%%" "%%~fa"
    ) | findstr /v "%_avoid%" && >nul move /y "%%~fa" .\no_resize
```

---

After this loop, the remaining files can be resized and/or converted using an additional for loop in your bat, where you'll treat it already creating the converted file in a relevant folder...

No need for a `:label/:function` for `errorhandler` and `pause` each file whichever is bigger, you can wait to process each one after the main job is finished...

Comment: This worked wonders! Thank you so much!